# how can I duplicates data based on a value in a dataset in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset as

## col col2 MaxCount

adf def  5

Need output as :

## col1 col2 EntryNumber

adf def 1

adf def 2

adf def 3

adf def 4

adf def 5

Is it possible with hive Context . plz help me

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I dnt know how  this can be done using HiveConext or SqlContext.

Comment: Is any other way to get the same . please forward your  tips

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. Tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck, and more about your problem. Where did the dataset come from? How was it constructed?

Answer (score 0):

```
val input = sc.textFile("filePath")
val result = input.mapPartitions(x => {
  x.flatMap(y => {
    val line = y.split(delimiter)
    val attribute = line(2)
    (i until attribute.toInt).map(i => {
      y+delimiter+i.toString
    })
  })
})
result.foreach(println)
```

Comment: with the help of above code we get the result (without using hiveContext or sqlContext)